# Should I use a database or a class?

Tags: python, database, class

I want to create something which keeps track of which tenants live in what apartment and does some other things like calculating ROI and keeping track of costs.

What is recommended to do in this case? Use a class which would be called Apartments and then have tenants that live within a certain instance / apartment? Or would it be better to keep track of something like that with a database? Or perhaps a combination of those two?

I don't really know what the possibilities are and I tried googling / stackoverflowing it but I couldn't really find an answer to my question.

PS. the programming language I'll be using is Python.

Comment: You’ll need a combination of both. A class(or an instance of it) will only be available when the program is in memory or running. As soon as you exit the program, the instance of the class will get destroyed. You need to save the class into something. Enter database(persistence). Read about ORMs like SQLAlchemy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first question you should be asking yourself is whether you want your data to be **persistent** meaning - do you want your data to be gone once you stop your application or not?

If you don't need persistence, then you don't need database.

If the question is - yes, I want persistence - then we can dig deeper. Do you need the data to be accessible by different users, possibly doing modifications to the data at the same time? If no, then don't use a database. Store the data in some file in a format that is easy to parse.

If - again - we say yes, then databases are one way to solve the issue. Next question would be - which database do you want? Relational, key-value, document, graph? (Usually if you don't know the answer to this question mean you want a relational one...)

As Sushant mentioned a minute ago - you will also need some ways to represent the data in your application. You will have some structures (let's call it a model), and you will load the data into your model and store the data from into the database. ORM tools do that for you, but if it is the first time for you to see such things, you might also be good without.

Having said that, you are up to a long journey. Remember to have fun.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. At first I thought the file-solution would be best. It probably also is at the moment, but I think I want to create this into some larger app at some point which would do all the bureaucratic stuff for me. So I guess I'll just have to go all in now and learn stuff about databases so that I don't have to catch up later on when my project grows larger. Thanks a lot again for increasing my beginners knowledge! ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is really no "right way" to design how anything works (I know this comment could start a fun argument) but there are ways that are better and make a little bit more sense.

It really depends on what your program has to do.

You can store all your tenant information in a json file (try https://realpython.com/python-json/) and read, save and write a database that way. If you want it work without local file storage, your going to have to read more on databases https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mongodb_getstarted.asp.

You can store the tenant objects you create through serialization, using something like https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/pickle-python-tutorial.

If you are just going to keep a list of tenants and some properties with, tenants, I would recommend storing in json.  You could even create a separate object that lets you interact cleanly with the tenant data you get from json.

If you sit down with a pen and paper and plan what you are going to do and how you are going to do it, you can usually avoid a lot of questions like this - however -  I think this is more a situation where you don't know what you can do with information storage/retrieval/manipulation and that is just gonna be google and practice.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I will look into the links you provided. The pen and paper tip is also very handy, will do that. And indeed, I don't really know what is possible yet, so thanks for adding a piece of your knowledge to mine, cheers! ;)

Comment: Yeah no problem - I had the same problem when I started, it's kinda like "I know what I want to do, I just don't know if there is a way to do it".  You'll start to know what is possible/what isn't as you get going.